# Regexp javascript - url match with localhost

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a **simple** regexp for url validation, but not very good in regexing..

Currently I have such regexp: `(/^https?:\/\/\w/).test(url)`

So it's allowing to validate urls as `http://localhost:8080` etc.

What I want to do is **NOT** to validate urls if they have some long special characters at the end like: `http://dodo.......` or `http://dododo&&&&&`

Could you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this?

```js
/^http:\/\/\w+(\.\w+)*(:[0-9]+)?\/?(\/[.\w]*)*$/
```

Will match: `http://domain.com:port/path` or just `http://domain` or `http://domain:port`

```js
/^http:\/\/\w+(\.\w+)*(:[0-9]+)?\/?$/
```

match URLs without path

Some explanations of regex blocks:

*Domain:* `\w+(\.\w+)*` to match text with dots: `localhost` or `www.yahoo.com` (could be as long as *Path* or *Port* section begins)

*Port:* `(:[0-9]+)?` to match or to not match a number starting with semicolon: `:8000` (and it could be only one)

*Path:* `\/?(\/[.\w]*)*` to match any alphanums with slashes and dots: `/user/images/0001.jpg` (until the end of the line)

(*path* is very interesting part, now I did it to allow lone or adjacent dots, i.e. such expressions could be possible: `/.` or `/./` or `/.../` and etc. If you'd like to have dots in *path* like in *domain* section - without border or adjacent dots, then use `\/?(\/\w+(.\w+)*)*` regexp, similar to *domain* part.)

*** UPDATED ***

Also, if you would like to have (it is valid) `-` characters in your URL (or any other), you should simply expand *character class* for "URL text matching", i.e. `\w+` should become `[\-\w]+` and so on.

Comment: It will also match `http://domainport` (no colon ":" between the domain and port). Which I would like to *not* match.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match `ABCD` then you may leave the start part..

For Example to match `http://localhost:8080`

' just write

```
/(localhost).
```

if you want to match specific thing then please focus the term that you want to search, not the starting and ending of sentence.

Regular expression is for searching the terms, until we have a rigid rule for the same. :)

i hope this will do..

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how complex you need the Regex to be. A simple way would be to just accept words (and the port/domain):

```
^https?:\/\/\w+(:[0-9]*)?(\.\w+)?$
```

Remember you need to use the `+` character to match one *or more* characters.

Of course, there are far [better & more complicated solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) out there.

Answer (score 1):

```
^https?:\/\/localhost:[0-9]{1,5}\/([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)
```

#### match:

- https://localhost:65535/file-upload-svc/files/app?query=abc#next

#### not match:

- https://localhost:775535/file-upload-svc/files/app?query=abc#next

#### explanation

- it can only be used for localhost
- it also check the value for port number since it should be less than 65535 but you probably need to add additional logic

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty late to the party but now you should consider validating your URL with the `URL` class. Avoid the headache of regex and rely on standard

```js
let isValid;
try {
    new URL(endpoint); // Will throw if URL is invalid
    isValid = true;
} catch (err) {
    isValid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. This will allow localhost and live domain as well.

```
^https?:\/\/\w+(\.\w+)*(:[0-9]+)?(\/.*)?$
```

Answer (score -2):

```
^https?:\/\/(localhost:([0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6})?$
```

Will match the following cases :

- http://localhost:3100/api
- http://localhost:3100/1
- http://localhost:3100/AP
- http://localhost:310

Will NOT match the following cases :

- http://localhost:3100/
- http://localhost:
- http://localhost
- http://localhost:31