# Laravel URL validation using validator

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'am trying to validate a URL to make sure it doesn't contain localhost. I have done it using if-else and want to do it using custom validator. I am lost how it could be done by validator.

```
if((strpos($request->input('url'), 'localhost') !== false) || 
    (strpos($request->input('url'), 'http://localhost') !== false) ||  
    (strpos($request->input('url'), 'https://localhost') !== false) ||  
    (strpos($request->input('url'), '127.0.0.1') !== false) ||
    (strpos($request->input('url'), 'http://127.0.0.1') !== false) ||
    (strpos($request->input('url'), 'http://127.0.0.1') !== false))
{
    return response()->json([
        'error_description' => 'Localhost in not allowed in URL'
    ], 403);
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules Just read the docs

Comment: @Markus: I have read that but I am unable to convert this into the custom validator.

Answer (score 3):

You can already achieve it with existing validation and a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696796/regexp-javascript-url-match-with-localhost):

```php
'url' => 'regex:/^http:\/\/\w+(\.\w+)*(:[0-9]+)?\/?$/',
```

I did not test this, but it is creative with existing validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `url` validator of `laravel`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-url

Comment: `The field under validation must be a valid URL.` - `localhost` is a valid URL, so I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
'url'   => ['regex' => '/^((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)$/'],
```

I hope this will be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
$messages = [
  'url.required' => 'Đường dẫn bắt buộc nhập',
  'url.url' => 'Url không hợp lệ'
];
    
$data = request()->validate([
  'url' => 'required|url',
], $messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `active_url` rule that checks if a url has existing A or AAAA records and is reachable. localhost won't validate true in this case.

[Reference Here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-active-url)